# Jewish way to describe depleted batteries?

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy, words

Is there any halachic or hashkafic issues with saying that a battery has "died"? It is a well known Torah tradition, halachically and hashkafically, for us to avoid words like this, and speak with a refined tongue. See the first sugya in Bavli Pesachim for example; "Or Le'Arba Asar", where the word "night" is considered a negative word. All the more so, "died"?

The word "died" is euphemised in Torah, Mishna and Gemara often (but this is always talking about a person rather than an inanimate object). However, the phrase has become the de facto way to describe a battery depleting in modern English tongue. Using the word "depleted" is never used in every day speech, and I am unaware of any other ways people commonly describe this situation? "Ran out" maybe?

Comment: I am struggling with this question. If the Torah says a person died without issue why would it be problematic to use it on a soulless, inanimate object?

Comment: @Dov the Torah also uses the word night a lot. Sounds like a separate question

Comment: Bereishis 25:8 - "וַיִּגְוַ֨ע וַיָּ֧מׇת אַבְרָהָ֛ם" - sounds pretty dead to me??

Comment: There's an old joke about the Duracell factory employing a Rabbi to stand at the end of the production line and keep saying "I wish you a long life" to all of the batteries coming out

Comment: @Dov I said "often"

Comment: The Machlokes in Bava Kama whether "died" is an accurate description for broken utensils ... Rabbi Yehuda holds "broken=dead."

Comment: @Shalom if you can turn that into an answer that would be amazing

Comment: *Es hot gestorben*?

Comment: @RabbiKaii A [Sefaria search for 'וימות'](https://www.sefaria.org.il/search?q=%D7%95%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA&tab=text&tpathFilters=Tanakh&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance) gives me 124 results for the Tanakh. How often is it euphemised?

Comment: @TamirEvan I don't know, it's not really possible to use a search engine, and also I'm not sure the relevance. A lot of focus on my weaker point (which I admitted is probably not relevant) isn't reducing the question afaik, but bli neder I will try and find better sources when I get a chance. I am rather surprised that this question seems odd to some - all my Jewish life I've been exhorted to not say words like "died", and the gemara in pesachim is a rock solid source that _should_ carry the whole question

Comment: "_The word 'died' is euphemised in_ ... _However, the phrase has become the de facto way to describe a battery depleting in modern tongue._" Where I live, they usually say "[הסוללה נגמרה](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%94+%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%94%22)", in the the Modern _Hebrew_ tongue.

Comment: @RabbiKaii"_I am rather surprised that this question seems odd to some - all my Jewish life I've been exhorted to not say words like 'died'_ ..." Was that exhortation extended to [not] saying it when talking about animals? To the extent I was exhorted on the matter, it was in being polite to the departed, as well as their loved ones still living, by not equating them to animals, or insects. "... _and the gemara in pesachim is a rock solid source that should carry the whole question_". How often is 'אור' used for 'night' in the Mishnah (especially when _not_ discussing _Bedikat Chametz_)?

Comment: @TamirEvan I'm sorry, I think our thoughts are not on the same wavelength on this. I'd be happy to try and see things your way separately but for the sake of this question, I will leave your questions unanswered and wait for someone on the same wavelength to comprehend my question and offer an answer (or an improvement on the wording, which I may attempt myself at some point)